# How to make a java program that calls upon the methods of another class?

Tags: java

One file that has the methods and the other to call upon the methods of the first. The assignment is asking for the user to input some numbers that corresponds to his actual pin.

The pin is 99508 and then each number from 0 to 9 will be represented by a random digit of either 1,2, or 3. so the user will input something like "22312" instead of his actual pin.

Now I think I have the first part done, but I am unsure how to make a second file to call upon the first's methods.

Here is my first file:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class Authenticate 
    { 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

    int[] actual_password = {9, 9, 5, 0, 8}; 

    int[] random_nums = new int[10]; 

    int[] entered_digits = new int[actual_password.length]; 

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
    { 
    random_nums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1; 
    } 

    System.out.println("Welcome! To log in, enter the random digits from 1-3 that"); 
    System.out.println("correspond to your PIN number."); 
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println("PIN digit: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"); 
    System.out.print("Random #: "); 
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    { 
    System.out.print(random_nums[i] + " "); 
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println(); 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter code."); 
    String s = keyboard.next(); 

    int Index = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<actual_password.length; i++) 
    { 
    String z = keyboard.next(); 
    entered_digits[Index++] = s.charAt(0) - '0';
    } 
    if (isValid (actual_password, entered_digits, random_nums))
    { 
    System.out.println("Correct! You may now proceed."); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    System.out.println("Error, invalid password entered."); 
    } 
    }
```

And here is what I have for the demo to use the methods:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class AuthenticateDemo
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          Authenticate myAuthenticate = new Authenticate();

    myAuthenticate.genRandomNum();

    System.out.println("Welcome!  To log in, enter the random digits from 1-3    that");
    System.out.println("correspond to your PIN number.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("PIN digit: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
    System.out.print("Random #:  ");


            myAuthenticate.printRandomNum(); 
     }
    }
```

Now I get errors at the `myAuthenticate` lines and I am not sure where I got the code wrong. Any help would be greatly

Comment: In the class `Authenticate`, there are no methods, everything is in the main. You have to put them in a method and the main is obsolete because you aren't running that file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to call upon the methods of another class is to make sure that the methods in question have a static keyword in their method header. The example is taken from a homework I did in my Computer Science 1 class (I'm a freshman in college, so if someone has a better answer, please answer haha):

A given method using recursion:

```
public class Homework8Methods{
public static ArrayList<int[]> permuteArray(int[] array) {
    ArrayList<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    permute(result, array, array.length);
    return result;
}

public static void permute(ArrayList<int[]> permutations, int[] a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        permutations.add(a.clone());
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        swap(a, i, n - 1);
        permute(permutations, a.clone(), n - 1);
        swap(a, i, n - 1);
    }
}

public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

}

And then in a separate class that had the test cases for this particular problem:

```
System.out.println("\nPart 3:");
    nums = new int[]{4, 7, 1, 2};
    ArrayList<int[]> perms = Homework8Methods.permuteArray(nums); //Here is where the method is called from the separate class. It goes (ClassName).(MethodName with/without parameters, depending on the method in question).
    System.out.println("permuteArray({4, 7, 1, 2}):");
    // uncomment the following code once you have implemented permuteArray()        
    for (int[] array: perms) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks, This is a good reference to me. I can understand what my code needs.

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call non-existent methods of another class. In order to use the `myAuthenticate.genRandomNum();` method in the demo class, you need to make a method in the `Authenticate` class like this:

```
public int genRandomNum(){
   //code to generate that random number
   return thatNumber;
}
```

You can access this by saying something like

```
int randomNum = myAuthenticate.getRandomNum();
```

It looks like you're just trying to organize the code by putting it in different files. You can't really do that all too well in Object Oriented Programming. The variables that are in the Authenticate class can't be accessed by the AuthenticateDemo class unless 1. they are public and can be returned by `myAuthenticate.variableName` or 2. they are private and you write an "accessor" method to return the value which can be gotten by writing `myAuthenticate.getVariableName()`

If you wanted to use the code as you have it right now, you could rewrite the `main(String[] args){...}` method of Authenticate to something like `execute(){...}` and call it using `myAuthenticate.execute();` This sort of misses the point of Object Oriented though.

Comment: Thanks, I am starting to see where I went wrong. I will now try to edit my code to see if it works.